# Recursive Function Big-Oh Complexity

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
Algorithm multiply(n, m)
PRE: n :: Integer, greater than or equal to 0
m :: Integer
POST: ????
RETURNS: the product, n * m
if (n = 0)
return 0
else if (n is even)
return multiply(n/2, m+m)
else
return m + multiply((n-1)/2, m+m)
endif
```

Is this function O(logn) because it is dividing n in every recursive case? I am studying for my midterm and I want to make sure I am doing this correctly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.

Although this is the case here, be careful, a divisor in a recursive call is not always an indication of logarithmic complexity.